# Cordova can't access Sencha's global variable

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch-2

I am having a serious issue. 
I am building an sencha touch app using cordova build(using sencha cmd5). In Sencha the AppName.app.globalVarible is working fine, but after build the global variable in no more accessible in cordova. Here the code is as follows.

Global variable(`baseUrl`) code in `app.js`.

`Ext.application({
    name: 'Myapp',
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost/myproject/admin',
.............`

This is working fine when i call this global variable baseUrl by `Myapp.app.baseUrl` in sencha app. (I mean in the browser)

But when i run `sencha app build native`(using cordova build)
then i am getting the following error.
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'baseUrl' of undefined`(near Myapp.app.baseUrl).

> Please don't tell  me to change it to util. i don't want it.

Please help regarding the same. 
Thank You

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what's the issue here, but you can do one thing here and it'll work for sure. Instead of defining a variable in `app.js`, try this:

- Create a new js file and named it `global.js`.(NOT IN APP FOLDER)
- Create a desired variable in `global.js`.In your case,

```
 var global = {
     baseUrl: 'http://localhost/myproject/admin'
 }
```

- Now add this global file reference in `index.html`.
- Now whenever you want baseUrl, just write `global.baseUrl`

Comment: Ya i know it will work but its kind of util stuff. But i don't want to use util i want to call global variable by `Appname.app.globalvariable`

Comment: I don't understand from where util is falling here. I think there's no need to deal with util if you adding this code.

Comment: I mean i dont want to add any extra file. i want to access global variable from app.js only